# What is the difference between two ways to manipulate strings in C?

Tags: c, string, pointers

I want to copy a string "str" to p . First I used the code I commented out, but the output was empty. So I tried the code that is below the commented area, and it worked. What is the difference between the two methods to manipulate strings in C? Thanks in advance.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

    int main(void)
    {
        char *str = "laekfja";
        char *p = (char*)malloc(51 * sizeof(char));

        //First try.
        /*  while(*str)             
                {                   
                    *p++ = *str++;  
                }                   
            *p = '\0';
            printf("%s\n", p);    
        */

        //Second try.
        int i = 0;
        while(i < strlen(str))
            {
              p[i] = str[i];
              i++;
            }
        p[i] = '\0';
        printf("%s\n", p);
        return 0;  
    }
```

Comment: The two ways are almost perfectly equivalent, and both should work, more or less.  You just need to keep a handle on the *original* value of `p` in your first try, as the next comment explains.

Comment: In first way, you increment p pointer while copying but you did not reset it back to starting point.

Comment: You could add `char *orig_p = p;` after the `malloc` call, and then  use `printf("%s\n", orig_p);` at the end.  (Also, you should get in the habit of *always* checking the return value of `malloc` to make sure it succeeded.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both methods work to copy the string.  The error in the first method is in printing the copied string out when the loop is complete:

```
printf("%s\n", p);
```

At this point, `p` is pointing to the last character inserted into the copy, the null character, not the beginning of the string.  So the `printf()` correctly prints nothing.